# How to ActiveRecord get query values rather than models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I have a query that is working as expected, but the result is coming back as an array of models, rather than the values. The query transforms a date, and then groups by that date.

The ActiveRecord query statement:

```
Participant.
  select(
         "count(*)",
         "date_trunc('month', participants.completed_at) as Date").
  group('Date')
```

which returns:

```
[ #<Participant id: nil>,
  #<Participant id: nil>,
  #<Participant id: nil>,
  #<Participant id: nil> ]
```

Interestingly, the relevant data is there on the Participant... for example, if I look at the model it shows me the information I need:

```
pry(main)> results.first.attributes
=> {"count"=>70, "date"=>2014-04-01 00:00:00 UTC, "id"=>nil}
```

But it's sort of strange, since neither `count`, nor `date` are attributes of that model.

The raw SQL query:

```
SELECT
  count(*),
  date_trunc('month', participants.completed_at) as Date
FROM "participants"
WHERE "participants"."deleted_at" IS NULL
GROUP BY Date;
```

Which returns:

```
 count |        date
-------+---------------------
  5742 | [NULL]
   590 | 2016-05-01 00:00:00
   798 | 2016-06-01 00:00:00
   293 | 2017-01-01 00:00:00
```

I know that I can simply map the results to format it the way I want, but I would like to get the data directly from the ActiveRecord statement as an array or hash, rather than on a model object.